# How to create a Gradle build file that publishes a Java project to Ivy repo with sources, correctly?

Tags: java, gradle, ivy

First of all: I've found so much information about this, both on SO, Google, Gradle documentation etc., it makes my head spin, but no one single source has told me the **correct** way of publishing a plain old java project, with sources, to an Ivy repository, with correct configurations, maven classifiers, Ivy types, etc. Here's as far as I have gotten:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'

group 'com.example'
version '0.1.0'

repositories {
    ivy {
        name 'local'
        url "${System.properties['user.home']}/localivy"
    }
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.java
    // If the classifier isn't put here, the source jar overwrites the compiled jar
    classifier "sources"
}

publishing {
    publications {
        ivy(IvyPublication) {
            configurations {
                sources {}
            }
            from components.java
            descriptor.status = 'release'
            artifact(sourceJar) {
                type "source"
                conf "sources"
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        add project.repositories.local
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishIvyPublicationToLocalRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'ivy' to repository 'local'
   > Could not parse Ivy file file:/Users/markus/code/publish-test/build/publications/ivy/ivy.xml
      > Problem occurred while parsing ivy file: Cannot add artifact 'publish-test.jar(source)' to configuration 'sources' of module com.example#publish-test;0.1.0 because this configuration doesn't exist!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Specifically, I am trying to not have the source in the runtime configuration (because clients that get the library then get the sources even though they only want the compile dependencies).

Also, I am a bit confused that publishing sources (and javadocs for that matter) isn't a standard part of the *java* Gradle plugin, like publishing the compiled jar is.

Any help from someone out there? Thanks!

PS: My reference ivy.xml file is from Google Guava 15.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="com.google.guava"
        module="guava"
        revision="15.0"
        status="release"
        publication="20130906215249"
    >
        <description homepage="">
        Guava is a suite of core and expanded libraries that include
    utility classes, google&apos;s collections, io classes, and much
    much more.

    Guava has two code dependencies - javax.annotation
    per the JSR-305 spec and javax.inject per the JSR-330 spec.
        </description>
        <m:dependency.management__org.easymock__easymock__scope>test</m:dependency.management__org.easymock__easymock__scope>
        <m:dependency.management__com.google.caliper__caliper__scope>test</m:dependency.management__com.google.caliper__caliper__scope>
        <m:dependency.management__junit__junit__scope>test</m:dependency.management__junit__junit__scope>
        <m:dependency.management__org.truth0__truth__scope>test</m:dependency.management__org.truth0__truth__scope>
        <m:properties__test.include>**/*Test.java</m:properties__test.include>
        <m:properties__gpg.skip>true</m:properties__gpg.skip>
        <m:dependency.management__org.mockito__mockito-core__scope>test</m:dependency.management__org.mockito__mockito-core__scope>
        <m:properties__truth.version>0.13</m:properties__truth.version>
        <m:properties__project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</m:properties__project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <m:dependency.management__javax.inject__javax.inject__version>1</m:dependency.management__javax.inject__javax.inject__version>
        <m:dependency.management__org.truth0__truth__exclusion_0>com.google.guava__guava</m:dependency.management__org.truth0__truth__exclusion_0>
        <m:dependency.management__junit__junit__version>4.8.2</m:dependency.management__junit__junit__version>
        <m:dependency.management__com.google.caliper__caliper__version>0.5-rc1</m:dependency.management__com.google.caliper__caliper__version>
        <m:dependency.management__com.google.caliper__caliper__exclusion_0>com.google.guava__guava</m:dependency.management__com.google.caliper__caliper__exclusion_0>
        <m:dependency.management__org.truth0__truth__version>0.13</m:dependency.management__org.truth0__truth__version>
        <m:dependency.management__com.google.code.findbugs__jsr305__version>1.3.9</m:dependency.management__com.google.code.findbugs__jsr305__version>
        <m:properties__sonatypeOssDistMgmtSnapshotsUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</m:properties__sonatypeOssDistMgmtSnapshotsUrl>
        <m:dependency.management__org.easymock__easymock__version>3.0</m:dependency.management__org.easymock__easymock__version>
        <m:dependency.management__org.mockito__mockito-core__version>1.8.5</m:dependency.management__org.mockito__mockito-core__version>
        <m:maven.plugins>org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-enforcer-plugin__1.0|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-enforcer-plugin__1.0|null__maven-gpg-plugin__1.4|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-enforcer-plugin__1.0|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-enforcer-plugin__1.0|null__maven-gpg-plugin__1.4|org.apache.felix__maven-bundle-plugin__2.3.7|null__maven-compiler-plugin__null|null__maven-source-plugin__null|null__maven-dependency-plugin__null|org.codehaus.mojo__animal-sniffer-maven-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-javadoc-plugin__null</m:maven.plugins>
    </info>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="runtime dependencies and master artifact can be used with this conf" extends="runtime,master"/>
        <conf name="master" visibility="public" description="contains only the artifact published by this module itself, with no transitive dependencies"/>
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="this is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths."/>
        <conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it. It is only available on the compilation classpath, and is not transitive."/>
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath." extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test" visibility="private" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases." extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="system" visibility="public" description="this scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository."/>
        <conf name="sources" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the source artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the javadoc artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="optional" visibility="public" description="contains all optional dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="guava" type="bundle" ext="jar" conf="master"/>
        <artifact name="guava" type="source" ext="jar" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources"/>
        <artifact name="guava" type="javadoc" ext="jar" conf="javadoc" m:classifier="javadoc"/>
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.google.code.findbugs" name="jsr305" rev="1.3.9" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="javax.inject" name="javax.inject" rev="1" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <override org="org.easymock" module="easymock" matcher="exact" rev="3.0"/>
        <override org="org.truth0" module="truth" matcher="exact" rev="0.13"/>
        <override org="com.google.caliper" module="caliper" matcher="exact" rev="0.5-rc1"/>
        <override org="org.mockito" module="mockito-core" matcher="exact" rev="1.8.5"/>
        <override org="javax.inject" module="javax.inject" matcher="exact" rev="1"/>
        <override org="junit" module="junit" matcher="exact" rev="4.8.2"/>
        <override org="com.google.code.findbugs" module="jsr305" matcher="exact" rev="1.3.9"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Or is it just easier to switch to a Maven repository (perhaps still using Ivy for the actual publishing)? What do people do when publishing their artifacts with Gradle?

Comment: The core problem is that there is no universally agreed upon way to publish sources in Ivy. That's why you have to configure Gradle manually and tell it what to do.

Comment: Gradle doesn't use Ivy anymore, not even when publishing to an Ivy repository. Working with Maven repositories is definitely easier, also for the problem at hand.

Comment: Perhaps I should try going the Maven route. Thanks for your comment!